# Definition of [=] in cpp syntax

Tags: c++

I am looking at source code for android and came across the following code:

```
unique_fd local_end(sfd[0]);
unique_fd remote_end(sfd[1]);
sfd[0] = sfd[1] = -1;

// dump blocks until completion, so spawn a thread..
std::thread dump_thread([=, remote_end { std::move(remote_end) }]() mutable {
           int err = service->dump(remote_end.get(), args);

           // It'd be nice to be able to close the remote end of the socketpair before the dump
           // call returns, to terminate our reads if the other end closes their copy of the
          // file descriptor, but then hangs for some reason. There doesn't seem to be a good
          // way to do this, though.
          remote_end.reset();

          if (err != 0) {
              aerr << "Error dumping service info: (" << strerror(err) << ") " << service_name << endl;
          }
});
```

Now, I don't understand what does this part mean:

```
[=, remote_end { std::move(remote_end) }]
```

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: It's a lambda capture list. Do you know what lambdas are?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat is it like anonymous class in Java?

Comment: You may want to grab **_A Tour of C++_** to get up to speed on modern C++ programming. Or maybe [another good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) as well.